# How to hide our IP Address when i do DOM Parse HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing, ip, hide

i want to hide my ip address when i do DOM Parse HTML,i just parsed schedule flight from other website,and i want to hide my ip,so they don't banned my ip. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You should find alternatives (possible API?), instead of scraping data.

Comment: If you are going to get IP blocked for doing it, maybe there is a reason they don't want you doing it?

Comment: maybe i can use random ip, but how to random my ip address ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I undestand correctly your question. 
Do you need get contents from website (web scraping)?
Than, before get contents, set proxy ip (you can find many proxy addresses in [hidemyass](http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/)), so your real ip is hidden.
Try this code:

```
$withProxy = array(
               'http' => array(
                            'proxy' => 'tcp://221.10.40.238:80',
                            'request_fulluri' => true,
                         ),
             );
$strProxy = stream_context_create($withProxy);

$getPage = file_get_contents("http://www.website.com", False, $strProxy);
```

You can test this code in 'whatismyip': you will read Ip proxy and not your real ip!

```
$getPage = file_get_contents("http://www.whatismyip.com/", False, $strProxy);
```